# Add a new record to database after checking value

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data into a database fine with the user entering a reference number eg 1234. Can I change my insert to not require the user to input the value and for the last value entered to be checked and then the reference number being inserted be incremented by one and then inserted with the other data. Bit of a new bee. Here is my current code

```
$Reference_No = $_POST['Reference_No'];
$Property_Name = $_POST['Property_Name'];
$Property_Area = $_POST['Property_Area'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties (Reference_No, Property_Name, Property_Area)
VALUES ('$Reference_No', '$Property_Name', '$Property_Area')");
```

Comment: You could make `Reference_No` an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Comment: I understand yes - i also need the new reference number lower down in my code on the same page - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

interogate the database for the Reference NO (where property name matches if you need it)

`$reference_no_query = mysql_query("SELECT Reference_No FROM properties WHERE Property_Name = $Property_Name");`

pull the Reference No out of the database

`$Reference_no = mysql_fetch_array($reference_no_query)`

display the Reference no

`echo $Reference_no('Reference_no');`

you can (and should) tie the data to a variable then echo the var like this:

`$Reference_no_display = $Reference_no('Reference_no');`

then display it directly from the variable anywere and as many times as you want in the page below the query:

`echo $Reference_no_display;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Reference_No an AUTO_INCREMENT.

**Step 1:Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE properties (
   Reference_No int AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   Property_Name varchar(255),
   Property_Area varchar(255),
   PRIMARY_KEY (Reference_No)
)
```

**Step 2 : Set the start for  auto increment of primary key if you like**

```
 ALTER TABLE properties AUTO_INCREMENT=1234;
```

**Step 3: Insert the data into the table**

```
 INSERT INTO properties (Property_Name, Property_Area)
 VALUES ('$Property_Name', '$Property_Area')");
```

Comment: Hi yes  I also need the new reference number lower down in my code on the same page - any ideas on this

Comment: Not understand what you say. Can you describe more clearly what you need?

Comment: I understand this will insert the data but i need to know what the new reference number is after it is inserted for some more code lower down

Comment: Oh! now understand what you ask about. First Reference _No will be 1234 ,then it will be incremented by one if you insert another data  and Reference _No will be 1235. It will go on in similar way if you insert more data . The Reference_No will look like this 1234,1235,1236,1237,......

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick for the final bit

```
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```